# adding view on the bottom of listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

After inizializing the custom adapter for my ListView it draw the first part of the dataset. Now I want to add some other view at the bottom of the listview. But when i use notifyDataSetChanged it doesn't refresh the listview.

setup

```
                ListView messages = findViewById(R.id.latest_messages);


                adapter = new AdapterChat(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.element_chat_other, inputItems);


                messages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
                messages.setAdapter(adapter);
                messages.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
```

update not working:

i add a new object in the arraylist and then recall the adapter for refreshing data.
But view still not showing:

```
                inputItems.add(new DTOChat(fromCC,messageCC, tsCC, idCC));
                adapter = new AdapterChat(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.element_chat_other, inputItems);


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

ADAPTER

```
public class AdapterChat extends ArrayAdapter<DTOChat > {

Context context;
int rand = 0;

public AdapterChat(Context context, int risorsaId,
                   List<DTOChat> items) {
    super(context, risorsaId, items);
    this.context = context;
}




public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //controllo se c'è gia un layout
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final DTOChat content = getItem(position);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = preferences.getString("username", "");

    if(content.getFrom().toLowerCase().equals(username.toLowerCase())) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.element_chat_other, null);
        }
    } else {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.element_chat_me, null);
        }
    }

    final TextView msg = convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
    msg.setText(content.getMessage());


    //data
    TextView ts = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ts);
    String[] chunks = content.getTs().split(" ");
    String[] chunks2 = chunks[1].split(":");
    ts.setText(chunks2[0]+":"+chunks2[1]);




    return convertView;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

With the following statement, you assign an instance of `AdapterChat` to *adapter*

```
adapter = new AdapterChat(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.element_chat_other, inputItems);
```

Then you set this instance as adapter for the `ListView`

```
messages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Some time later, you add a new item to the data list *inputItems* and assign another instance of `AdapterChat` to *adapter*

```
inputItems.add(new DTOChat(fromCC,messageCC, tsCC, idCC));
adapter = new AdapterChat(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.element_chat_other, inputItems);
```

Now, the old instance is still set as the current `ListView` adapter but when you call  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` you notify the recently created instance which you assigned to *adapter*.

You can keep *adapter* the way it is (don't create a new instance), simply add the new item to *inputItems* and directly afterwards call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: doing like you suggest i got this error:  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: @LorenzoCatalano - then you've got one step further (adapter tries to work with the modified list), so mission at least partially accomplished (in the scope of your question). It seems however that there is an issue with your adapter implementation. If you like, you can paste your AdapterChat code as well as the stack trace into your question and we can look into it

Comment: added to the post

Comment: @LorenzoCatalano - and the stack trace? And which is the line in which the Exception occurred?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
inputItems.add(new DTOChat(fromCC,messageCC, tsCC, idCC));
// here no need to create new adapter instance only add below line
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: this error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: I use arraylist : ArrayList<DTOChat> inputItems = new ArrayList<DTOChat>();